# 'Not enough memory for file map' when attempting update to linked server using VFP ODBC driver

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-foxpro

I have a linked server in SQL Server 2008 that's using the MDASQL provider to access a Visual Fox Pro ODBC DSN.

I'm receiving the below errors when attempting to perform simple queries:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "odbclinkedserver" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Not enough memory for file map.".

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "odbclinkedserver" reported an error. The provider ran out of memory.

Msg 7306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot open the table "odbctable" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "odbclinkedserver".
```

I'm trying to run this update query that is the goal of the activity:

```
update odbclinkedserver...odbctable
set memofield = m1.blob
from sqlsvrtable m1
where m1.int_1 = odbctable.int_1
and m1.int_2 = odbctable.int_2
and m1.time= odbctable.time
and odbctable.date= '2011-06-28'
```

I have also attempted some simpler queries and still receive the same errors:

```
select top 1 * from odbclinkedserver...odbctable
```

The DSN source is a Free Table directory. The sizes of the files involved are:

- odbctable.dbf = 62MB
- odbctable.cdx = 9.85MB
- odbctable.fpt = 200MB

I have configured the SQL instance to start with the '-g' parameter with a value of 1024 so that a gig of memory is set aside for this operation (this is a test server with no other activities).

Reference used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx

Given the size of the files involved, the simplicity of the queries, and that I've set aside a gig of RAM for it to use, I am running out of ideas of how to resolve this problem.

Can anyone suggest a solution to resolve these errors so that I can update the target dbf with the update query above?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you seem to have enough memory set aside when I had the same issue a stop and start of the SQL Server service followed by running `sp_dropserver` and `sp_addlinkedserver` was enough to resolve the issue:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT srv.name FROM sys.servers srv WHERE srv.server_id != 0 AND srv.name = N'DBF_XXX')EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'DBF_XXX', @droplogins='droplogins'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'DBF_XXX', @srvproduct=N'Microsoft Jet', @provider=N'VFPOLEDB', @datasrc=N'D:\Data To Import\XXX\data', @provstr=N'dBASE 5.0'

--For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ########
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'DBF_XXX',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'Admin',@rmtpassword='########'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not violating any of VFP's ODBC restrictions in either the environment or the table structures. Especially note that ODBC hasn't been suported for some time. Check [here](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFPODBCdriver) for a good list of restrictions. Is using the OLEDB driver a possibility for you? If so do a web search for "VFPOLEDB driver download" to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the info - judging from the list I'm not violating any of the restrictions. I have used the OLE DB provider however I get different errors with that.